# Viewing Installation Log on Failed Ubuntu 12.04 Installation?

Tags: 12.04, grub2, system-installation, hp

I have two identical HP DL380p G8 machines. One of the DL380p machines completed an "unattended" installation of Ubuntu 12.04 w/o issue. The problem DL380p completes the reboot but is unable to load the OS.

I get a message on the console stating; `Non-system disk or disk error`. I am guessing that the Grub installation/configuration messed up but, I'm unable to look at the installation log to find out because the machine reboots too quickly. I'm remote and I don't have the option of hunting down a different .iso image or anything like that.

Again, the first one worked and I just need to get at the installation log file before the machine reboots so I can tell what the heck went wrong.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This particular question has been resolved.  I resolved it myself by adding some code to the end of the preseed file that I was using for the installation.  The line I added was something like `d-i preseed/late_command sleep 999999999999999 ...`  Perhaps a simple shell command "read" would also have sufficed?  In any event, problem solved.  Thanks.